# hyperparameter tuning error on google ai platform: "The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1"

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, google-ai-platform

When training a deep learning model in google cloud AI platform, using hyperparameter tuning (my hyperparameter configuration information is in a YAML file), I am getting this error:

```
Hyperparameter Tuning Trial #2 Failed before any other successful trials were completed. 
The failed trial had parameters: batch_size=11, learning_rate=3.527059074944887e-05, .
The trial's error message was: The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1
```

As the error message is a bit generic, I am having a difficult time trying to understand where could be the problem.

My YAML config file:

```
trainingInput:
  hyperparameters:
    goal: MINIMIZE
    maxTrials: 2
    maxParallelTrials: 2
    hyperparameterMetricTag: loss
    enableTrialEarlyStopping: FALSE
    params:
      - parameterName: batch_size
        type: INTEGER
        minValue: 8
        maxValue: 16
        scaleType: UNIT_LINEAR_SCALE
      - parameterName: learning_rate
        type: DOUBLE
        minValue: 0.00001
        maxValue: 0.0001
        scaleType: UNIT_LINEAR_SCALE
```

Comment: can you provide more detailed logs on the error message? Check for traceback logs on the error.

Comment: Check Traceback logs (https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/troubleshooting#getting_information_from_the_logs)